# kubuntu 14.04 - wireless connects but cannot ping or navigate

Tags: wireless, networking

I just installed kubuntu 14.04. Wi-fi scans correctly the networks, connects correctly via WPA to the wifi network, but can't ping 8.8.8.8 or navigate.
Any hints?

Here follows a report:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:    trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux pippo-EasyNote-TM86 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:036d]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8174] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8186]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0402:9665 ALi Corp. Gateway Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country IT:
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (N/A, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 40), (N/A, 27), DFS
    (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), NO-OUTDOOR

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"NETWORK"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Digicom-ADSL

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [NETWORK] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192se
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Giusti1:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA
    InfostradaWiFi-682C88: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
    Alice-53393313:  Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    Giusti3:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA
    Visca:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
    TINA:            Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 84 WPA
    Telecom-64125432:Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WEP
    Palandri:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA
    *NETWORK:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    Vodafone-23638645: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.1
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254
    DNS:             8.8.8.8

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=24 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETWORK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000f2c76e70
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000942756C676172696E69
                    IE: Unknown: 010802040B161224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD9A0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B000103104700100000000000000001000300A0A244EEA31021000C4D696368656C616E67656C6F10230008576176652035344310240016312E31312D445F52315F54523036395F416E6E65784D1042000A4A3935303033373731391054000800060050F204000110110014576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020004
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706495420010D10
                        Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Palandri"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000041225feb92
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000850616C616E647269
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### lsmod #####

rtl8192se              63196  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8192se
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se
mac80211              626489  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192S/8191S 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE    <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming    <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B9B9518158623D8BAB67493
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008174sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008173sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008172sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008171sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008192sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE    <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming    <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B6B8AA929B5F982954A6DE1
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE    <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming    <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C21FC2F90947540319DE390
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x1692 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8174 (rtl8192se)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[   17.728391] rtl8192se: FW Power Save off (module option)
[   17.728439] rtl8192se: Driver for Realtek RTL8192SE/RTL8191SE
[   17.728439] Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
[   17.832745] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   21.946944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   21.947349] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   23.778987] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   23.800518] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[   23.800686] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   23.802903] wlan0: authenticated
[   23.803162] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   23.803167] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   23.806201] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   23.827867] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   23.831337] wlan0: associated
[   23.831348] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   23.919324] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
[   23.942512] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   23.942523] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[   23.942789] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   23.944917] wlan0: authenticated
[   23.945071] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   23.945074] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   23.946115] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   23.984809] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   23.988280] wlan0: associated
[   24.041625] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 6)
[   38.107385] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   38.118084] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[   38.118343] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   38.120460] wlan0: authenticated
[   38.120612] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   38.120616] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   38.122603] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   38.145767] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   38.148813] wlan0: associated
[   38.266657] Modules linked in: ctr ccm bnep rfcomm bluetooth joydev acer_wmi sparse_keymap intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm psmouse serio_raw snd_hda_codec_hdmi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev arc4 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi rtl8192se snd_seq_midi_event rtl_pci rtlwifi snd_rawmidi mac80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 lpc_ich snd mei_me mei soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ahci libahci nouveau i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper drm tg3 mxm_wmi ptp pps_core video wmi
[   38.266775]  [<ffffffffa03be3ad>] ? rtl_is_special_data+0x2d/0x110 [rtlwifi]
[  381.671337] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  390.067548] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  390.280023] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[  390.280168] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  390.382948] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[  390.486842] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[  390.590912] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[  391.535969] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  391.545892] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[  391.546125] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  391.548669] wlan0: authenticated
[  391.548913] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  391.548916] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  391.550649] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  391.596789] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  391.600554] wlan0: associated
[  582.097726] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  598.154410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  631.452108] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  631.473552] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  631.475159] wlan0: authenticated
[  631.478830] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  631.481317] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  631.485031] wlan0: associated
[  631.485049] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  635.515632] wlan0: disassociated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 2)
[  635.518292] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  642.908732] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  642.919778] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  642.921731] wlan0: authenticated
[  642.923971] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  642.926351] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  642.929061] wlan0: associated
[  646.956700] wlan0: disassociated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 2)
[  646.963474] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  662.459811] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  662.470682] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  662.472535] wlan0: authenticated
[  662.479096] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  662.481604] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  662.484815] wlan0: associated
[  705.101241] wlan0: disassociated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 2)
[  705.120643] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  706.273791] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  706.283773] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  706.392182] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[  706.496203] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[  706.600176] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[  720.336770] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  721.221957] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  721.242533] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[  721.242677] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  721.246826] wlan0: authenticated
[  721.247067] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  721.247074] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  721.248467] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  721.297096] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  721.300761] wlan0: associated
[  721.300780] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  721.360052] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
[  721.380999] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  721.381018] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[  721.381173] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  721.383374] wlan0: authenticated
[  721.383637] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  721.383645] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  721.384439] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  721.428976] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  721.432633] wlan0: associated
[  721.497652] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 6)
[  737.157631] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  737.168055] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[  737.168239] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  737.173524] wlan0: authenticated
[  737.173721] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  737.173726] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  737.176502] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  737.219723] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  737.222615] wlan0: associated
[ 1309.995149] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1314.127336] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1314.343456] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 1314.343730] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1314.444774] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 1314.548741] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 1314.652726] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[ 1315.593635] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1315.603762] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 1315.604027] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1315.606867] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1315.607097] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1315.607104] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1315.608386] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1315.646120] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1315.649754] wlan0: associated
[ 1373.467843] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1428.699247] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1428.709982] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 1428.710220] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1428.712196] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1428.712405] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1428.712412] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1428.714431] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1428.745197] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1428.748192] wlan0: associated
[ 1902.002145] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 3)
[ 1903.164402] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1903.175085] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 1903.175328] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1903.177561] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1903.177755] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1903.177760] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1903.179676] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1903.222563] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1903.225564] wlan0: associated
[ 2556.853348] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 3)
[ 2558.008353] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 2558.018573] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 2558.018897] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2558.021228] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2558.021490] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2558.021498] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2558.023234] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2558.044082] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2558.046873] wlan0: associated
[ 2901.791297] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 3)
[ 2902.941916] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 2902.952939] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 2902.953144] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2902.955514] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2902.955881] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2902.955888] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2902.957341] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2902.977797] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2902.980958] wlan0: associated
[ 3245.482726] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 3)
[ 3246.640940] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 3246.651027] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead
[ 3246.651406] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 3246.655119] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3246.655402] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3246.655411] rtl8192se 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3246.655683] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 3246.670990] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3246.673919] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thank you!